# PUG: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:15)

Tags: npm, syntax-error, pug, pugjs

No matter if I use gulp pug or just pug, I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:15)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2488:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:623:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:600:59)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVarStatement (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:973:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:751:17)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:672:23)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:529:15)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3378:37)
    at reallyParse (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\index.js:22:16)
    at findGlobals (C:\Users\freet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\index.js:35:11)
```

Because something is wrong in this file even if it looks like every other file in my project (and there are a lot of them):

```
extends ../layouts/layout

block variable
    - var headerType == "main";

block content
    include ../helpers/mixins

    .academy-page
        .top-section.js-screen.on-screen
            .top-container
                .top-mask
                    .text-wrap
                        h3 Academy
```

The error appears only when I enter the line with `.top-mask`. Before that everything's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In PUGJS, don't [declare variables](https://pugjs.org/language/case.html) with a semi colon at the end and have a single equals.

```
- var headerType == "main";
```

Should be

```
- var headerType = "main"
```

Comment: @ankaankina When assigning variables, you need to have a single = not ==.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I just found the solution to this by digging into the node_modules. for you I would start with opening the file AT `../AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug\node_modules\acorn-globals\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js`

```
Parser.pp$1.parseVarStatement
```

go to line 973 and log out the variables at that line, if they don't make any sense continue moving down to the next line in the stack trace towards

```
Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel line 672
```

repeating each log until it gives you something clearer to work with. The pug template will parse everything possible until it 'breaks' and that will give you a very accurate place to look at for your exact problem. **IE** just beyond that last log